# Disable hover on specific div

Tags: html, css, hover

When I hover over my #icon div, an image appears. When I remove the mouse from #icon the image disappears.

**THE PROBLEM**

If I hover over the space where the image will appear if I hover over #icon, the image appears. I've tried anything, so I really hope you can help.

I need to remove all hover effects on my `#image-divs`

**HTML**

```
<div id="box">
    <div id="icons1">
        <div id="image1"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="icons2">
        <div id="image2"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="icons3">
        <div id="image3"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="icons4">
        <div id="image4"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS EXAMPLE**

```
#box #icons1 #billede1 {
    height: 450px;
    width: 1000px;
    margin-left: -186%;
    margin-top: 150px;
    background-image: url(../html_css/billeder/1.jpeg);
    background-position: center;
    background-size: cover;
    opacity: 0.0;
    transition: opacity 0.5s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: opacity 0.5s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 0.5s ease-in-out;
}
```

Comment: Add a working demo or fiddle

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Use `pointer-events:none`

```css
div{pointer-events:none}
div:hover{color:red;}
```

```html
<div>Hover over me</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

best way is to use `pointer-events:none;`

```
#image-divs{
   pointer-events:none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Notice that you to specify every hover for every div while you are using id's, you need to specify the hover effect for every div, now you should use this :

```
#image1{
display:none;
}

#icons1:hover #image1
display:block;
}
```

this means, whenever you hover the icon1, image1 will be displayed, and so.

you can also try the opactiy:0; and opacity:1;